# Enum & Switch Case

Tags: asp.net, enums, switch-statement, case

Hi I am using enums converted to a string with a switch but it doesn't work. It gives compilation error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'userControl_commontop.UserType' to 'string'

The code is:

```
private void CommonTopChangesnew(string usertype)
{

    switch (usertype.Trim().ToUpper())
    {
        case UserType.NORMAL :
            hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
            hlkMRTQuery.Enabled = false;
            hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
            hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
            break;
        case UserType.POWER :
            hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
            hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
            hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
            break;
    }
}

enum UserType
{
    NORMAL,
    POWER,
    ADMINISTRATOR
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code fragment; it's currently unreadable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the userType parameter in to an enum value using this function:

```
object Enum.Parse(System.Type enumType, string value, bool ignoreCase);
```

as

```
UserType utEnum =  Enum.Parse(UserType, userType, true);
```

and then you can call your switch statement as:

```
switch (utEnum)
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

The enumeration is not a string, any more than a constant `const int MY_VALUE = 1;` is a string.

You should change your string into an Enum:

```
switch ((UserType)Enum.Parse(usertype, typeof(UserType))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The first option probably won't work as switch requires case statements to be constant.

Comment: @ShaulBehr I know this is old...but Hari is perfectly correct - the first example WON'T work. That's because switch statements require the cases to be constant (though if there is a way around this, I'd be very eager to hear it).

Comment: @Maverick - acknowledged, albeit several years later!  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should try this:

```
enum UserType
{
  NORMAL,
  POWER,
  ADMINISTRATOR
}

private void CommonTopChangesnew(string usertype)
{
  switch ((UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType), usertype, true))
  {
    case UserType.NORMAL:
      hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
      hlkMRTQuery.Enabled = false;
      hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
      hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
      break;
    case UserType.POWER:
      hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
      hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
      hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function accepts a parameter of type string and then you use the same parameter to compare types belonging the Enum. Here lies the conflict.

Your function should instead be :

```
private void CommonTopChangesnew(UserType usertype)
{

  switch (usertype)
  {
    case UserType.NORMAL :
      hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
      hlkMRTQuery.Enabled = false;
      hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
      hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
      break;
    case UserType.POWER :
      hlkSAD.Enabled = false;
      hlkReqViewer.Enabled = false;
      hlkSendnotif.Enabled = false;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a String with an Enum.

You should pass an Enum to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Change your CommonTopChangesnew to accept a UserType enum as a parameter

or

Option 2:
Use Enum.Parse to convert your string to a UserType enum in your switch block:

(UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType), usertype)